# Правильно отобразить количество согласных букв в счетчике

Tags: javascript

Пишу программу, которая считает количество согласных букв в предложении введенном пользователем, но возникло 2 вапроса на которые никак не могу найти ответа:

1) Если написать 2 или более одинаковых согласных, то он посчитает их за 1. Думаю что проблема в методе includes, но не знаю чем его заменить

2) Как искать буквы независимо от регистра?

```
var consonants = 'б в г д ж з й к л м н п р с т ф х ц ч ш щ B C D F G H J K L M N P Q R S T V W X Y Z';
var consonantsArr = consonants.split(" ");
var consonantsSumm = 0;// Согласные

if(document.getElementById('ravno').checked == true) {

    var originalTextArr = originalText.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0; originalTextArr.length > i; i++){

        for (var q = 0; consonantsArr.length > q; q++){
            if(originalTextArr[i].includes(consonantsArr[q])){
                consonantsSumm ++;
            }
        }

    }

    }
```

Вот какой результат получается сейчас 'ррр' = 1, 'ррп' = 2 и т.д. Нужно чтобы считалась каждая

Comment: *считает количество согласных букв в предложении* Всего или разных? `аббв` - результат 2 или 3?

Comment: Разных. рр = 1, ррп = 2, ррпп =2

Comment: Тогда при решении "влоб" заменяйте очередную согласную на пустую строку и проверяйте, изменилась ли длина переменной. И добавьте эту информацию в текст вопроса - это важно!

Comment: Такой результат получается или должен получиться? Пишите внимательно!

Answer (score 1):

Для учёта регистра воспользуйтесь toLowerCase();

А решение задачи вот:

```js
var str = 'Привет всем всем.';
var len = str.match(/[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/igm).length;
console.log(len);
```

Comment: К сожалению мы еще не проходили регулярные выражения и "/igm" я вижу впервые. Есть другой способ?
В любом случае, спасибо за ваш ответ.

Comment: См. комментарий к вопросу и пояснение автора.

Comment: Можно, но подлинее. Да и здесь вроде всё просто же.
Вот можете здесь глянуть https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp
И
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: Повторю явно - автору нужно количество уникальных согласных.

Comment: @Juzo, ничего страшного в регулярных выражениях нет. Это только на первый взгляд страшно. Когда-то вам всё равно придётся начинать. Это решение самое быстрое и короткое.

Answer (score 1):

**Самое короткое и быстрое решение:**

```js
var str = 'Здравствуйте, товарищи!';
//чтобы искать буквы независимо от регистра переводим их все в нижний регистр:
str = str.toLowerCase();
var arr = str.match(/[бвгджзйклмнпрстфхцчшщbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/igm);
var uniqueArray = arr.filter(function(val, i, array)
{
 return array.indexOf(val) === i
});
console.log(uniqueArray.length); //8
```

**Справка:**

- [Регулярные выражения в JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
- [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы проверять все буквы в одном регистре, приводите строку к одному регистру верхнему `.toUpperCase()` или нижнему `toLowerCase()`.

Первый вариант считает количество уникальных согласных:

```js
const string = 'Проверка';

let consonants = 'БВГДЖЗЙКЛМНПРСТФХЦЧШЩBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ';
let array = [];
let consonantsSumm = 0;
for (letter of string) {
  if (consonants.indexOf(letter.toUpperCase()) > -1 && array.indexOf(letter.toUpperCase()) == -1) {
    consonantsSumm++;
    array.push(letter.toUpperCase());
  }
}
console.log(consonantsSumm);
```

Второй вариант считает количество согласных:

```js
const string = 'Проверка';
let consonants = 'БВГДЖЗЙКЛМНПРСТФХЦЧШЩBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ';
let consonantsSumm = 0;
for (letter of string) {
  if (consonants.indexOf(letter.toUpperCase()) > -1) {
    consonantsSumm++;
  }
}
console.log(consonantsSumm);
```

Comment: Тоже не смотрите, что автору нужно. А нужно ему количество уникальных согласных, а не вообще.

Comment: @Akina, спасибо за замечание, внес изменения в ответ, теперь, надеюсь правильно.